# Why does my crontab not work?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am planning to run some bash scripts every minute, and I wrote:

```
* * * * * bash ~/Dropbox/temp_scripts/run_all_scripts
```

in crontab.

It was supposed to run every minute, but it did not work. Does anyone have idea why this happens?

Comment: Try using the full path instead of ~

Comment: This job runs every minute.

Comment: Also is your script marked executable?

Comment: Can you follow the debugging steps on the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) and update your post with the findings?

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for pointing this out! I have editted the question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, the mode of it is 774.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have already modified it to the full path. Three minutes passed, and nothing happened. Maybe I need to do some debugging.

Comment: Add full path to script_1.sh, script_2.sh ... in your script.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: Add I/O redirection: `>/tmp/run_all_scripts.out 2>/tmp/run_all_scripts.err`.  Review the contents of the files after a minute or two has passed.  Consider recording the environment to see if that's part of the problem.  If you still don't get anything (the files in `/tmp` are not created), then you've got issues with `cron`; the daemon isn't running, or your user does not have permission to use it (but `crontab` isn't telling you that), or you've not submitted your crontab to the program (what does `crontab -l` say?), or … whatever is really wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! I have already fixed it! The reason why it does not work is I used "ls -a *.sh" in the script, and when the crontab did not find any *.sh files in the folder it was executing. When modifying it to "ls -a $HOME/Dropbox/temp_scripts/*.sh", everything works!  This debugging technique is quite helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a comment into an answer.*</sup>

Add I/O redirection to the command line in the `crontab` entry:

```
>/tmp/run_all_scripts.out 2>/tmp/run_all_scripts.err
```

Review the contents of the files after a minute or two has passed. Consider recording the environment to see if that's part of the problem.  And consider using `bash -x` instead of just `bash`.

If you still don't get anything (the files in `/tmp` are not created), then you've got issues with `cron`; the daemon isn't running, or your user does not have permission to use it (but `crontab` isn't telling you that), or you've not submitted your `crontab` to the program (what does `crontab -l` say?), or … whatever is really wrong.

Note, too, that the output from `cron` jobs is normally (well, at least sometimes — on Mac OS X for a system I currently use, and Solaris for another that I've used previously) emailed to the person whose job it is. You should review the email on the system.

> *Thank you! I have already fixed it! The reason why it does not work is I used "`ls -a .sh`" in the script, and when the crontab did not find any `*.sh` files in the folder it was executing. When modifying it to "`ls -a $HOME/Dropbox/temp_scripts/.sh`", everything works! This debugging technique is quite helpful!*

It is, in many ways, the most basic of debugging techniques — make sure you see what is actually happening.  If you're not sure why a shell script isn't working, make sure you can see that it is executing and what it is producing in the way of output, and (very often) make sure you can see what it is executing with `bash -x` or equivalent.  (AFAIK, all shells support `-x` to trace the execution.)